# Any difference between Dialog.Display vs. Dialog.Show in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm playing around with the dialog options in Word VBA and I came across these two options. According to their documentations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dialog.display and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.dialog.show), they seem to be pretty much the same and I cannot really tell the difference if there's any. I assume there should be some differences otherwise they should have been fused into one function. I just got really confused and I probably lost some critical points. I didn't find any additional demonstration on this issue from my research. Could someone help explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for the `Show` method makes clear it "displays and carries out actions initiated in the specified built-in Word dialog box"

This makes it a combination of the `Display` and `Execute` methods.

Comment: So if I use 'Display' and click OK on a dialog, it won't really 'Execute'? Or if a 'Show' dialog times out, it'll automatically 'Execute'?

Comment: Display - user clicks OK and the dialog just closes. The return value tells you what the user clicked. What happens after that is down to your code. Show - user clicks OK and the dialog closes AND executes. If the dialog times out then it will just close as there was no user action.